# Why does Kafka Mirrormaker target topic contain half of original messages?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I want to copy all messages from a topic in Kafka cluster. So I ran Kafka Mirrormaker however it seems to have copied roughly only half of the messages from the source cluster (I checked that there's no consumer lag in source topic). I have 2 brokers in the source cluster does this have anything to do with this?

This is the source cluster config:

```
log.retention.ms=1814400000
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=2
offsets.topic.replication.factor=2
auto.create.topics.enable=true
default.replication.factor=2
min.insync.replicas=1
num.io.threads=8
num.network.threads=5
num.partitions=1
num.replica.fetchers=2
replica.lag.time.max.ms=30000
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
unclean.leader.election.enable=true
zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=18000
```

The source topic has 4 partitions and is not compacted. The Mirrormaker config is:

- mirrormaker-consumer.properties

```
bootstrap.servers=broker1:9092,broker2:9092
group.id=picturesGroup3
auto.offset.reset=earliest
```

- mirrormaker-producer.properties

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1
retries=2000000000
acks=all
max.block.ms=2000000000
```

Below are the stats from [Kafdrop](https://github.com/obsidiandynamics/kafdrop) on the source cluster topic:

| Partition | First Offset | Last Offset | Size | Leader Node | Replica Nodes | In-sync Replica Nodes | Offline Replica Nodes | Preferred Leader | Under-replicated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 13659 | 17768 | 4109 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  | Yes | No |
| 1 | 13518 | 17713 | 4195 | 2 | 2 | 2 |  | Yes | No |
| 2 | 13664 | 17913 | 4249 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  | Yes | No |
| 3 | 13911 | 18072 | 4161 | 2 | 2 | 2 |  | Yes | No |

and these are the stats for the target topic after Mirrormaker run:

| Partition | First Offset | Last Offset | Size | Leader Node | Replica Nodes | In-sync Replica Nodes | Offline Replica Nodes | Preferred Leader | Under-replicated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2132 | 4121 | 1989 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  | Yes | No |
| 1 | 2307 | 4217 | 1910 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  | Yes | No |
| 2 | 2379 | 4294 | 1915 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  | Yes | No |
| 3 | 2218 | 4083 | 1865 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  | Yes | No |

As you can see roughly only half of the source messages are in the target topic based on size column. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why aren't you using MirrorMaker2?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I'm using the mirrormaker from this image https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-kafka/ so the kafka version according to `./kafka-mirror-maker --version` is `7.0.0-ccs (Commit:c6d7e3013b411760)`.

Comment: Don't use the broker image, and the MirrorMaker1 scripts are essentially deprecated. `cp-kafka-connect`  image contains MirrorMaker2 https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/connect/mirror#mirrormaker-20

Comment: A little bit late, are you using a transactional producer?
In that case, transaction marks are not replicated as messages (they are not messages per se) but they take an space in source topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the issue happened because I was copying data from a cluster with 2 brokers to a cluster with 1 broker. So I assume Mirrormaker1 just copied data from one broker from original cluster. When I configured the target cluster to have 2 brokers all of the messages were copied to it.

---

Regarding the advice of `@OneCricketeer` to use Mirrormaker2 this also worked however it took me a while to get to correct configuration file:

```
clusters = source, dest

source.bootstrap.servers = sourcebroker1:9092,sourcebroker2:9092
dest.bootstrap.servers = destbroker1:9091,destbroker2:9092
topics = .*
groups = mm2topic
source->dest.enabled = true
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
offset.storage.replication.factor=1
auto.offset.reset=latest
```

In addition Mirrormaker2 can be found in `connect` container in this [KafkaConnect](https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/blob/main/tutorial/docker-compose-mongodb.yaml) project (enter the container and in the `/kafka/bin` directory there will be `connect-mirror-maker.sh` executable).

A **major downside** with Mirrormaker2 solution is it will add a prefix to the topics in target cluster (in my case new names would require changing application code). The prefix can't be changed in Mirrormaker2 configuration so the only way is to implement a custom Java class as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65115557/5863693).

Comment: From Kafka Connect cluster 7.x, you can use the replication policy org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.IdentityReplicationPolicy to avoid the prefix.
Otherwise you can implement the prefixless policy following the indications from the answer with more upvotes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59390555/is-it-possible-to-replicate-kafka-topics-without-alias-prefix-with-mirrormaker2